# Не получается в NestJS подключиться к MongoDB, Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, nestjs

У меня не получается подключиться к mongoDB в NestJS, mongoDB запущен в Windows, не в Linux.

Вот такое подключение к базе данных:

```
const mongoDBUrl = 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/nest-auth?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1';

@Module({
  imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot(mongoDBUrl),
        UsersModule,
        AuthModule
    ],
  controllers: [AppController, AuthController],
  providers: [AppService, AuthService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Также изменён файл `mongod.cfg`, в нём раскомментирована строчка и так написано:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Перед этим всем я заходил в MongoDB Compass, создавал пользователя со всеми правами для аутентификации в БД. Я могу успешно заходить в MongoDB Compass по такой же URI, но NestJS не хочет.

Полная ошибка в консоли такая:

```
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:08:26   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:08:59   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:09:32   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:10:05   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:10:38   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:11:11   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:11:44   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (7)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:12:17   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (8)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:12:50   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...
[Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:12:50   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at Mongoose.createConnection (C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:62:69)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:16:12)
    at C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:61:80
    at Observable._subscribe (C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\observable\defer.ts:55:15)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\mihinov\Desktop\my-works\nest-auth\node_modules\rxjs\src\internal\Observable.ts:244:19)
```

В чём может быть потенциальная ошибка?

Comment: Какую фактическую ошибку вы получаете? Возможно она поможет в поиске потенциальной. Не думаю, что NestJS вам говорит - "Не хочу подключаться к БД и точка" )

Comment: @SwaD [Nest] 20072  - 13.01.2023, 17:08:26   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...

Comment: @SwaD так и говорит)

Comment: Мдя... Ну не знаю, вдруг прокатит, если попробовать localhost заменить на IP 127.0.0.1 или адрес вашей машины поставить.

Comment: @SwaD да, через 8 минут после создания вопроса, я пришёл к ответу сам :D Как раз написал ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается, скорее всего в том, что указывать localhost через NestJS не получается. В MongoDB Compass можно, а у меня в NestJS не получается.

Можно зайти в `mongod.cfg`, посмотреть сюда:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Вместо localhost указывать этот IP-адрес 127.0.0.1
А также можно указать в этом файле свой IP адрес (можно узнать командой `ipconfig`), тогда к бд смогут подключаться другие компьютеры в локальной сети.

Напомню, что после каждого изменения `mongod.cfg` нужно выключать/включать службу MongoDB, чтобы она обновилась. Это можно делать командами:

Остановить

```
net stop mongodb
```

Включить

```
net start mongodb
```

Или можно перезагрузить Windows. Но легче остановить/включить службу